# Understanding Snells Law in seismic waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, refraction, earthquake

This is a homework question, Ill say it upfront.

The Problem is given so:

> Earthquake causes a wave that meets a boundary between two rock substances. Incoming wave speed is 25 m/s and angle is 9 degrees, refracted wave angle is 21 degrees. It is asked what is the speed of refracted wave?

At first it seems to me a simple snells law problem.... so I tried to apply Snells law like so sin(9) / sin(21) = 25 / x but answer I get from here is 21.7 m/s HOWEVER right answer is given and it is 57.3 m/s .... I do not understand what am I missing here?!?

Also lesson materials do not cover anything else really on the subject, I cant possibly imagine what am I missing.

Comment: Calculator in radian mode?

Comment: @garyp ive always used symbolab calculator, but it seems it took 21 as degrees but not 9 ?!?!?! you can see in this link
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/algebra-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bsin%5Cleft(21%5Cright)%7D%7Bsin%5Cleft(9%5Cright)%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B25%7D

Comment: A bug it seems.   You might report it.   BTW, I've never heard of Symbolab.  I'm going to poke around in it a bit.  It looks interesting (but buggy?)

Comment: I've looked at it and I don't like it.  Too much potential to be mis-used as an automatic problem solver that short-circuits the thought (and learning) process.   And it can be used to do homework for the user.  Finally the default units:  radians, centimeter, meter/sec?  Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snell's law is:  $$\frac{\sin\theta_t}{\sin\theta_i}=\frac{n_i}{n_t}$$  Where $n_x$ is the index of refraction.  So you've got transmitted/incident on the LHS and incident/transmitted on the RHS.  But you've been given velocity, which should invert the relationship - at least it would with electromagnetic waves.  So you'd get:  $$\frac{\sin\theta_t}{\sin\theta_i}=\frac{u_t}{u_i}$$ where $u_x$ is the velocity.

So your equation would then be: $$\frac{\sin(21)}{\sin(9)}=\frac{u_t}{25}=57.27\,\,\mathrm{m/s}$$  You've got the relationship correct.  It just must be a math error when you do the math.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you just miscalculated, sin(21)/sin(9)=2,29
and 25*2.29=57,3